# How does Tumblr determine the order of posts with the same post date outside the dashboard?

Tags: tumblr

On the dashboard, Tumblr posts appear in the order in which they were created (regardless of the date attached to them). But on the front-end (e.g. at mysite.tumblr.com), I'm seeing inconsistent order for posts **with the same post date and time**.

On a test Tumblr, I created the following posts in this order (post IDs in parens):

- Post A, dated 2013-08-14 7:00:00 (58279080752)
- Post B, dated 2013-08-14 7:00:00 (58279382194)
- Post C, dated 2013-08-15 7:00:00 (58314687302)
- Post D, dated 2013-08-15 7:00:00 (58314687868)

On my dashboard, they appear in proper reverse-chronological order of creation (assuming the IDs are sequential), D->C->B->A, but when I view my theme, they're in the order D->C->A->B.

So it seems that yesterday's posts are in reverse order of creation/ID, but today's posts are in the natural order of creation/ID. What would explain this inconsistency?

Note: I'm not interested in changing the order (I know I can just change the post date/time to do that). I'm interested in understanding the criteria Tumblr uses to order posts when they have the same date and time, which I cannot find documented.

**Update:** Here is an actual Tumblr I've created which displays this behavior: http://postordertest.tumblr.com/

Comment: Probably your themes use a grid-layout.. just a thought.

Comment: Good thought, but not in the case. It's a brand new Tumblr with the "Default" theme, which doesn't use a grid: https://www.tumblr.com/theme/36037

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I believe the answer to my own question is "no particular order".

I created [another test Tumblr](http://postordertest2.tumblr.com/), this time with three posts per identical datetime. For August 15 7am, the posts are displayed in 3rd-1st-2nd order of ID. But for August 14 7am, posts appear in 1st-3rd-2nd order of ID. No apparent pattern or consistency.

Then, I created two more posts dated August 15 7am. After publishing post G, Tumblr displayed the posts in 4th-3rd-1st-2nd order of ID. Again, no apparent order, other than the fact that the newest post appeared first. But here's where things got strange. After publishing a final Post H (same date/time), *the entire order of posts for that datetime changed*: from 4th-3rd-1st-2nd to 1st-5th-2nd-3rd-4th.

At this point, I can only conclude that Tumblr displays posts on blogs with the same date/time in no particular (or even consistently arbitrary) order.

Answer (score 0):

Tumblr determines the order of posts by Tumblr Post IDs in descending order.

Comment: This appears not to be the case. I've just added a link to a test Tumblr: the posts for day one (D & C) appear in descending order, but the posts for day two (A & B) appear in *ascending* order of Post ID. All times are 7:00am.